# Script to add multiple users in ubuntu (Bulk)

Tags: command-line

I need to add 10 users by a script in Ubuntu 12.04.

That could reduces time by adding users manually , and i can apply this script on other 
desktop .

Each user will has a specific user and in specific group.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script to automate user addition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/620478/shell-script-to-automate-user-addition)

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal and type: `vim /tmp/name` to create a file and the names of the users: eg:

```
vim /tmp/name
mika
mery
etc
```

Create User with Home Dir and default shell:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/name`; do useradd -m -d /home/$i -s /bin/bash $i; done
```

Create password for each user:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/name`; do passwd $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [newusers](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-create-multiple-users-accounts-in-batch.html) 
`echo "vivek:myUltraSecretPassword" | sudo newusers`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, I suppose.

```bash
for user in {1..200}; do
    echo "Creating user$user"
    cat <<EOF | adduser --gid 500 user$user
password
password
user$user







EOF
done
```

Comment: here all users are in the same group.

Comment: @guntbert They were in the OP's answer, as well. All were in 513 in the OP's.

Comment: true, but the question stated: "Each user will has a specific user and in specific group." - which you could achieve by omitting the `--gid 500` part.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/620483/402004),which says unless you have a whole lot of users to add the best way is to use `adduser` (for adding users) and `usermod` (for adding a user to a group) which takes care of a lot of things. If you still wish for some pre-made script, there is one [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-add-linux-system-users-from-a-text-file) and another one [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/08/create-multiple-users-linux.html), but I do not know if they really work for you

Answer (score -1):

It is my solution. I created file `/tmp/userlist` and added all users name, after completion of script it will create users and you can find user name and given random password in file `/tmp/userlist-created`. I know it is not perfect solution.

```
root@demobox:/root : cat /tmp/userlist
xyz1
zyz2
zyz3

root@demobox:/root : cat demo.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /tmp/userlist ]
then
for i in $(cat /tmp/userlist)
do
if [ -f /usr/bin/pwgen ]
then
PASSWORD=$(pwgen -1 -s 16)
else
PASSWORD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc "passwordNSR!@#$%0-9" | fold -w 9 | head -1)
fi
useradd -s /bin/bash -d "/home/$i" -m -p "$PASSWORD" "$i"
echo "$i --------- $PASSWORD" >>/tmp/userlist-created
done
else
echo "File /tmp/userlist not found"
fi
chmod 0600 /tmp/userlist-created

root@demobox:/root : ./demo.sh

root@demobox:/root : cat /tmp/userlist-created
xyz1 --------- FivSHfdbDCRffhc7
zyz2 --------- AIjFjE0bv3FslHnp
zyz3 --------- JazcGcKYp2Y0I3Rk

root@demobox:/root : egrep "xyz1|zyz2|zyz3" /etc/passwd
xyz1:x:9016:100::/home/xyz1:/bin/bash
zyz2:x:9017:100::/home/zyz2:/bin/bash
zyz3:x:9018:100::/home/zyz3:/bin/bash
```