# I need to make a batch of users

Tags: bash, users

I had written some code that would allow me to make a batch of users based on a file with usernames in it. But it eventually went from just a few lines to about 50, and I deleted it. There has got to be a better way, and I'm stuck.

My goal is to have a bash script that would make multiple users with passwords, and custom UID, and add to groups. Could anyone show me an example of a script that would do this?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/410712/script-to-add-multiple-users-in-ubuntu-bulk)? (Even though it has no accepted question)

Comment: Actually that may do nicely :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the policy is, but since the referenced question was not accepted, you should probably post the solution that worked for you as an answer and mark as resolved :)

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo newusers /tmp/userlist.txt
```

In the userlist.txt file, each line should contain user data in the following syntax:

```
username:password:User ID:Group ID:Comments:Userhome directory:User shell
```

Since the userlist.txt file contains users' passwords, it should not be stored in a human readable form after you have finished creating the new users. My advice is to store the userlist.txt in a file that is encrypted with a strong password, and then after you have stored the encrypted userlist.txt file securely, to delete the original userlist.txt file from the `/tmp` directory so that nobody can read the user passwords as plain text.

For more information about the syntax of the `newusers` command type:

```
man newusers
```

In the man results for `newusers` the GECOS field is also known as the comment field for a user.

Check `/etc/passwd` file to see if the new users are created. The easy way to do it is to show a list of only the users' names (There is less unnecessary information to read that way.) using the command:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I saw this and thought wow! Unfortunately, there's a weird long-standing bug on ubuntu where this prog can't do more than 2 users at a time. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1266675

Comment: wow! indeed and this bug affects an Ubuntu 16.04 user, however when I tested the 2 users example from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1266675 on Ubuntu 16.04 the bug was not reproduced. If this bug affects you, then instead of creating a batch of users, as a workaround until the bug is fixed create the users one user at a time.

Comment: Yah, I'm working on that at the mo. For me, annoyingly complex to get  working, esp when there's such an elegant method available :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need **pwgen** tool to make random passwords

Make a file (users.txt) with usernames delimited with \n:

```
userA
userB
userC
```

Write a bash script that reads from stdin:

```
while read user
do
  password=$(pwgen -N 1)
  sudo useradd $user -m -s /bin/bash 
  sudo passwd $user $password

  echo Created $user with password $password
done
```

Lastly, call the script: cat users.txt | /bin/bash my_script.sh

Comment: but I also need a custom UID and Grouping,

Comment: Put groupname and UID in user.txt. Like this userA:groupA:UIDno. Add IFS=: and while read user group uid in script. Also add flags to command useradd to match your needs. (Eg. -g for groups)

Comment: `-bash: pwgen: command not found`

Comment: yum install pwgen