# automate adduser and add to group in one shell scrpit

Tags: bash, scripts

[image: this is the question i have planed it out how the program wil work in a flowchart]

So i am looking for a quick and easy way to auto mate adduser and at the same time add that user that you are creating to a group. I have tried many way of writing in shell scrpit and it has not worked need help. Or does anyone already have this code.

i have first used this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m -p $pass $username
         [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "    Failed to add a user!"
fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question, and although hints may be given it is generally expected that the student work out the processes themselves.

Comment: There are many scripts to do just this . http://bfy.tw/2qzB first result here was http://askubuntu.com/questions/410712/script-to-add-multiple-users-in-ubuntu-bulk . See also http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-force-users-to-change-passwords/

Comment: We do not solve homework. But you can show your script in a question and the error it produces or what's wrong with it and ask for help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer is not really solving your homework task (this is intended because you should think a bit yourself), but in my opinion there is no need to automate the user creation process further than it already is.

**Just use `adduser` instead of `useradd`!**

Example (creating user `example`, display name `Mr. Example`):

```
$ sudo adduser --gecos "Mr. Example" example 
Adding user `example' ...
Adding new group `example' (1002) ...
Adding new user `example' (1002) with group `example' ...
Creating home directory `/home/example' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Or, if you prefer not to see the status messages, redirect the STDOUT to `/dev/null`, as the important password prompt is printed through STDERR:

```
$ sudo adduser --gecos "Mr. Example" example > /dev/null
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

There's not really much more you can automate or simplify than this command above. It creates a suitable primary group for the new user automatically, as well as a home directory.

To add an existing user to another (already existing!) group, just use `adduser` as well:

```
$ sudo adduser example cdrom
Adding user `example' to group `cdrom' ...
Adding user example to group cdrom
Done.
```

I don't see how anything can be simplified and automated more.